# How to wrap bash command substitution output in quotes

Tags: bash, sh

Trying to pull strings out of files found with bash's Parenthesis () - Command substitution. I am using this command

```
strings $(locate '.tps' |egrep -i customer | egrep -i billing)
```

And it works fine with files that have no spaces.  When a file has a space this happens

```
strings: '/sales/rep/company/October': No such file
strings: 'bill': No such file
strings: 'and': No such file
strings: 'invoice': No such file
strings: 'customer': No such file
strings: 'name.tps': No such file
```

If I try wrap the command in double quotes

`strings "$(locate '.tps' |egrep -i customer | egrep -i billing)"`

It concatenates all the files that it finds into one BIG filename

Comment: `sh`, or `bash`? Two different shells, and they have different facilities  for the purpose.

Comment: `man xargs` ...

Comment: Note that the easy-and-wrong "fix" is to just set `IFS=$'\n'`, but there are various and  sundry bugs  created by relying on unquoted expansion, even when `IFS` is set to only contain characters you genuinely intend to use as a  delimiter. (See what happens with a line containing only a `*` in that  case for an example).

Answer (score 3):

Doing this in bash with GNU tools might look like:

```
locate '.tps' | egrep -i customer | egrep -i billing | xargs -d $'\n' strings --
```

...or:

```
locate '.tps' | egrep -i customer | egrep -i billing | while IFS= read -r file; do
  strings "$file"
done
```

That said, it's not safe to use newline-delimited streams to represent lists of filenames  *at  all*, because files on common UNIX filesystems (including ext3, ext4, btrfs, etc) are permitted  to contain newlines themselves. With GNU locate:

```
locate -0 '*.tps' | egrep -i --null-data '(customer.*billing|billing.*customer)' | xargs -0 strings --
```